# How Can We Calculate the Integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How can we calculate the integral $$\int_0^1x\cdot 1_{\{y-1\leq x\leq y\}}dx ?$$

Do we have to take cases for $y$ so that $[y-1,y] \subseteq [0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that we need to consider different ranges for $y$. Specifically, $y <0$, $0\le y<1$, $1 \le y < 2$, and $y \ge 2$.

For $y < 0$ and $y \ge 2$, the integral is zero.

For $0 \le y < 1$, you need to compute
$$\int_{0}^{y} x \, dx,$$
and, for $1 \le y < 2$, the integral is 
$$\int_{y-1}^{1} x \, dx.$$

Comment: For $y<0$ we get an interval where the upper bound is $0$, but the integration bound is the integral $[0,1]$. For $y\geq 2$ we get an interval where the lower bound is $1$, but the integration bound is the integral $[0,1]$. So, in these two cases we have that $1_{\{y-1\leq x\leq y\}}=0$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, you are right.